# Printing rendered data on new HTML page using Jinja and Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

```
#Python code in flask
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_file():
    alist=[]
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.files:
            data=request.files["file"]
            data.save(os.path.join(app.config["FILE_UPLOAD"], data.filename))
            if(validate(alist)):
                flash("Validated")
            else:
                flash("Not validated")
    return render_template("index.html",alist=alist)

#Jinja code inside index.html
{% if dic|length>0 %}
    <p><a href="error.html" target="_blank">Check error</a> </p>
{% endif %}
```

On my website I'm uploading a file which will go to flask API to check if the file is valid or not. I have created a custom function for validation. I'm saving all the errors that I get in a list "alist". When I render it to my html page first I check if there is an error or not. If there is no error(i.e size of dlist is zero) then I'll keep my html page as it is and if there is an error(i.e size of dlist is greater than zero) then I'll show a link there which will open in new tab with all the errors.

How can I pass the rendered list "alist" to some other page and how to link them so that error is shown on page like http://127.0.0.1:5000/error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `/error` route which will get errors from the file you passed in.

Each time you have at least one error in the file, add a link in your template which calls this route and redirect to `/error` endpoint.

By the way, it's better to use `url_for()` method to handle redirections in your template.

Don't:

```py
    <p><a href="error.html" target="_blank">Check error</a> </p>
```

Do:

```py
    <p><a href="{{ url_for('error') }}" target="_blank">Check error</a></p>
```

On the other hand, you can get errors from your variable in your template like this :

```py
{% for item in alist %}
   <p>{{ item }}</p> #error
{% endfor %}

Hope it helped !
```